# Erro ao tornar CheckBox Visivel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Estou usando o seguinte codigo para tornar os CheckBox visiveis.

```
CheckBox: Array[1..15] of TcheckBox;


procedure TForm1.edt_variavelChange(Sender: TObject);
var valor,x,i  : integer;
 if valor = 2 then
    begin
         for i := 1 to 2 do
           begin
              TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Visible := true
              CheckBox[i].Visible := true;
     end;
```

porem ele da um `Acess Violation`, ao usar o debug e dar um `BREAK` no erro sou direcionado a esse código do Vcl.Controls

```
procedure TControl.SetVisible(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FVisible <> Value then
  begin
    VisibleChanging;
    FVisible := Value;
    Perform(CM_VISIBLECHANGED, Ord(Value), 0);
    RequestAlign;
  end;
end;
```

Como posso solucionar esse erro?

Comment: As checkbox esitem, são componentes criados?
Não seria o caso de realizar a busca por componentes e assim setar?

Comment: Colcoa o código inteiro

Comment: Eles existem, só estão setados como invisiveis. @Passella o que mais precisa do codígo? acho que todas as informações estão ai.

Comment: tente: if Assigned(CheckBox[i]) then CheckBox[i].Visible := True;

Comment: nada acontece @Passella

Comment: passa o código inteiro, fica mais facil de alguem te dar uma resposta

Comment: adicionei @Passella

Comment: voce não garante que sua variavel local valor seja 2, voce não setou os objetos no vetor CheckBox, verifique se o metodo FindComponent retorna realmente alguma coisa, espero que tenha ajudado

Comment: Retorna pois os edits se tornam visiveis, e o evento está no onchange então ao adicionar 2 na variavel valor, 2 edits se tornam visiveis, e o mesmo deveria se repetir para os checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crie um for onde o mesmo ira passar por todos os componentes se for checkbox ative o mesmo da seguinte forma:

```
for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
       if Components[i] is TCheckBox then
          TCheckBox(Components[i]).Visible := true;
    end;
```

ai você pode alterar conforme sua necessidade, colocando mais algumas validações se necessário.

Comment: Tive que adaptar, mas segui esse caminho, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que pode ser uma possibilidade desta forma, não testei o código:

```
procedure SetaCheckBox (bOp : Boolean);
var
    nmComp : TComponent;
    i : integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount-1 do
    begin
        nmComp := Form1.FindComponent(Form1.Components[i].Name);
        if Assigned (nmComp) and  (nmComp is TCheckBox) then
                TCheckBox(nmComp).Visible := bOp;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SetaCheckBox (false);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
        SetaCheckBox (True);

end;
```